# What are the effects of using color on RDIF key cards?

Tags: visible-light, waves, radio

Does using color on an RDIF radio key card affect how the waves are transmitted? Is there any possible interference caused by the color? Why or why not?

Comment: Ask longer, and if your question would be closed, then give a new try to the http://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2):

Generally RFID cards operate at a very low frequency compared to (say) WiFi. This means the RF signal is more penetrating. As for the paint, as long at it does not contain a lot of metal particles it does not matter what color it may be

Comment: More generally - "if the paint is not conducting, the color doesn't matter". But "gold colored paint" may well be conducting; even if it doesn't contain metal particles.